# Background colour mailchimp

Tags: html-table, outlook, html-email, mailchimp

I am using a MailChimp template which you can edit it for your needs.

So far I have successfully managed to (very carefully) remove all the sections I do not want and do some basic editing, but the background colour is not consistent in Litmus. I have run it through an html syntax checker and it came back clean.

I have read other posts that say that the body is often ignored and you should apply a background colour to a container - but as far as I can see, that has already been done here, but still does not work.

I tried inserting another row or table just after the initial table and setting a background color but it always comes back with a syntax error even though I match the pairs up at the end of the html.

I haven't got to the part where I set all the inner containers bg-color to white yet, but I want to try and fix the body color first before I spend any more time on it.

Any help would be great.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1aemmrz8vfe038/version%20stripped%20new.html?dl=0

Added: Have updated the file so the content containers are set to white.

Comment: Paste a snippet of the code with your question as well please. The dropbox has the full html and its hard to identify which one is causing your error.

Comment: Hi Syfer - thanks for your response. I actually solved this this morning.

Comment: How? Post it as an answer so please can see th issue resolved please.

Comment: Was just writing it - answer below

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this to account for Gmail and Yahoo which is where I was seeing it.

```
        <center style="background-color:#e6e6e6; width:100%;">
```

I added this just after the body tag (and closed just before the end body).